# I can't reach my server

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ftp

I have ubuntu 20.04 server hosting with `nginx`. My site is in word press. I was trying to install ftp by following documentation on Vultr. Suddenly, the connection with my site, lost  (502 bad gateway). I removed the firewall and everything backed to normal.

Today, I tried to finish ftp installation, and I faced the same issue. This time, when I remove the firewall, I'm receiving a warning on console as below:

```
<<uid is 0 but '/' owned to 1000>>
```

In addition, when I make a restart on console, I barely have time to see a red line says that failed to start php 7.4 or something like that. Please, help.

Comment: What commands were you using while setting up the FTP software? Based on your details, it looks like there was a `chown -r user:user /` somewhere, which is “a bad thing” 

Comment: You're asking for an explanation of what happened due to some commands you typed in, but you do not tell us what those commands are. I hope you can see that this is an ineffective way in which to seek help.